# How to make cytoscape-ctxmenu.js applicable on nodes with condition?

Tags: javascript, cytoscape.js

I´m using the cytoscape-ctxmenu.js extension in the graph and I would like to enable this extension only for nodes which has href which has a value and not null because sometimes I have the case that some activities has href parameter with null value.
Thanks for help

```js
cy.cxtmenu({
  selector: 'node[href]',

  commands: [{
    content: 'OpenWeb',
    select: function(ele) {
      window.open(this.data('href'));
    }
  }]
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding the question mark ? before the href solved my problem

```js
cy.cxtmenu({
  selector: 'node[?href]',

  commands: [{
    content: 'OpenWeb',
    select: function(ele) {
      window.open(this.data('href'));
    }
  }]
});
```